# Flutter riverpod I am not able to understand why my widget is not getting rebuilt

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

**My HomeScreen Widget is not getting rebuilt when there is a change in state of errorProvider**

## My Providers

```
GetWeather initialState = GetWeather();
final weatherControllerProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<WeatherController, GetWeather>(
  (ref) => WeatherController(
    weatherRepository: ref.watch(weatherRepositoryProvider),
    ref: ref,
  ),
);

class WeatherController extends StateNotifier<GetWeather> {
  final WeatherRepository _weatherRepository;
  final Ref _ref;

  // final LocationController _locationController;
  WeatherController({
    required WeatherRepository weatherRepository,
    required Ref ref,
    // required LocationController locationController
  })  : _weatherRepository = weatherRepository,
        _ref = ref,
        // _locationController = locationController,
        super(initialState);

  void getWeatherData(BuildContext context) async {
    final position = _ref.watch(locationControllerProvider.notifier).state!;
    final res =
        await _weatherRepository.getWeatherData(position[0], position[1]);

    res.fold(
        (l) => _ref
            .watch(errorProvider.notifier)
            .update((state) => l.message.toString()),
        (weather) => state = weather);
  }
}

final errorProvider = StateProvider<String?>((ref) {
  return;
});
```

## HomeScreen widget

```
class _HomeScreenState extends ConsumerState<HomeScreen> {
  bool unit = false;
  void getWeatherData(context, ref) async {
    await ref.watch(locationControllerProvider.notifier).getLocation(context);
    ref.watch(weatherControllerProvider.notifier).getWeatherData(context);
    ref.watch(errorProvider.notifier).state;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    GetWeather weather = ref.watch(weatherControllerProvider);
    String? errorMessage = ref.read(errorProvider.notifier).state;
    if (weather == initialState) {
      Future.delayed(
          const Duration(milliseconds: 50), () => getWeatherData(context, ref));
      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Weather'),
            actions: [
              IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.search)),
              Center(
                child: unit ? const Text('Celius') : const Text('Faranite'),
              ),
              Switch(
                value: unit,
                onChanged: ((value) {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      unit = value;
                    },
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: Center(
              child: ref.watch(errorProvider.notifier).state == null
                  ? const Loader()
                  : ErrorText(
                      error: ref.watch(errorProvider.notifier).state!)));
    } else {
      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Weather'),
            actions: [
              IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.search)),
              Center(
                child: unit ? const Text('Celius') : const Text('Faranite'),
              ),
              Switch(
                  value: unit,
                  onChanged: ((value) {
                    setState(() {
                      unit = value;
                    });
                  })),
            ],
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Text(weather.city!.name!),
          ));
    }
  }
}
```

I am changing the state of error provider when the res is of type Failure inside WeatherController so when that state is updated my widget is not getting rebuilt
How can I solve this and why is this happening

Comment: Stop using ref.read inside build!  Without ref.watch, you are not subscribed to changes, which will have exactly the impact you describe.

Answer (score 1):

`ref.read` -> use in callback and asynchronous operation

`ref.watch` -> use in build method and within other providers to have up-to-date data whenever a provider gets too old.

Change your code according to these rules and everything will work :)